# Eclipse automatic abstract method generator

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance, methods

In my eclipse project, I am making a bunch of classes that implement interfaces. When I check the box in the Create new class window, that says inherit abstract methods, or when I click on the name and say inherit abstract methods, it generates method stubs for those methods that need to be implemented. But the problem is, the argument names it generates are not correct. E.g. the parameters are called `sender`, `cmd`, `label`, and `args`, but they are generated as `arg0`, `arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3`. I've added the javadocs for the libraries that contain those interfaces, and I can confirm that they are because when i hover over the method name it shows me the correct arguments, but they still wont generate the names right. I'd like to know if there's a way to change or fix this.

Comment: How are your class and methods are named? Can you post some code? Remember that Eclipse autogenerator is heavily depended on JavaBean conventions

Comment: Are the Interfaces in the same project, another project or a jar?

Comment: The interfaces are in a maven dependency JAR, that has a javadoc attached.

Comment: @Pocketkid2 Do you have that JAR file imported into your project?

Comment: Isn't it already there? How would I import it further? I've added the repo and the dependency to the pom.xml and built the project using mvn install

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Once I added the source, (for me it was a local folder) then it loaded the correct names.